# Difference between non-greedy search and negated character set

Tags: regex

Is there any difference between these two regular expression patterns (assuming **single-line** mode is enabled): `a.*?b` and `a[^b]*b` ? What about in terms of performance?

Comment: It depends on the string to be matched, don't you think? )

Comment: @raina77ow No. How so? If you know of a string that will match one but not the other, that's exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: In terms of performance `a[^b]*b` will score over `a.*?b`

Comment: @Mark There's none, of course. And yes, I do understand that in both cases the engine should be smart enough to just look for the next `b`. The question is, whether it goes that way directly - or checks each letter from the beginning (the first case) / the end (the second).

Comment: @anubhava Why is that?

Comment: Due to backtracking involved in `a.*?b`

Comment: It's faster because of how the regular expression backtracks.

Comment: +1, would really like to hear a more detailed answer. Personally, I tend to use `.*?` when term-to-string ratio is low, and `[^]*` when it's quite high.

Comment: And yes, I've checked [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) up as well. )

Comment: @raina77ow The paragraph under "An Alternative to Laziness" is quite good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.*?b` has to check at each consumed character if it matches the pattern (i.e. if the next one is a `b`). This is called backtracking.

With the string `a12b` the execution would look like this:

- Consume `a`
- Consume the following 0 characters. Is the next one a `b`? No.
- Consume the following character (`a1`). Is the next one a `b`? No.
- Consume the following character (`a12`). Is the next one a `b`? Yes!
- Consume `b`
- Match

`a[^b]*b` consumes anything that isn't a `b` without asking itself questions and is much faster for longer strings because of that.

With the string `a12b` the execution would look like this:

- Consume `a`
- Consume anything that follows that isn't a `b`. (`a12`)
- Consume `b`
- Match

[RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) has a benchmark feature that will demonstrate that with the .NET regex engine.

Other than the performance difference, they match the same strings in your example.

However there are situations where there is a difference between the two. In the string `aa111b111b`

`(?<=aa.*?)b` matches both `b` while `(?<=aa[^b]*)b` matches only the first one.

Comment: That's nice, but the true point is: isn't regex engine smart enough to transform the first form to the second one, if they are destined to give the equivalent results? )

Comment: They are equivalent in this very case. But use the same tokens in a look-behind or a look-ahead and the situation might change. It's probably longer for the engine to figure out if there's a difference than to execute whatever you used.

Comment: @raina77ow I have updated my answer with an example where there's a difference.

Comment: Ok, can you please explain the results linked in the answer above?

Comment: Ah, look-behind with non-set length. A nice feature to have in regex, of course. But many of those I work with don't have it, sadly. )

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your both regex, naming them as:

```
NONGREEDY = /a.*?b/;
GREEDY = /a[^b]*b/;
```

I named negative regex as GREEDY but is just the name.

You can check [test-non-greedy-vs-greedy-performance](http://jsperf.com/test-non-greedy-vs-greedy-performance) on JsPerf and run the tests to see it by yourself. Feel free to modify the string to perform different test cases.

You can check different test that guys have added and the benchmark results varies depending of the input string.

Below test is for string: **ab**

[image]

[image]

Below test is for string: **axb**
[image]

Below test is for string: **afdkjsklfjsdlkfjsdlkfjsdlkjflskdjflsdfjjflksdjfb**
[image]

**After these tests the performance seems to vary depending of the string you are parsing.**

Hope this test can help answering this question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the negative character set regex was about 2.5 faster in a .NET engine.

Comment: Now check [this test](http://jsperf.com/test-non-greedy-vs-greedy-performance/3) instead. That's exactly what've I commented about. )

Comment: @raina77ow very nice, that's interesting too.

Comment: Do you have evidence that in this case JsPerf is specially relevant or is generally comparable to PCRE, etc. etc.?

Comment: @ajm475du my friend, nobody said that. I liked this question so I try to help by providing a shareable test case that all of you can use, modify and try. It is just another option to help the community. Actually, I learnt more from Vache answer than mine.

Comment: @Fede Thanks. I mean, I would imagine most regex engines are similar in many features and perhaps this feature in particular. But I don't happen to know that. You've demonstrated the insight that it's not hard to make an empirical test as well as providing the result for one particular engine.

Comment: @ajm475du glad to read that. What I really don't understand is why people downvoted without leaving a comment to improve the question.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the comment. I'll update the answer with more samples. Thanks for the +1, really appreciate it

Comment: You can make a more assertive claim that "performance seems to vary". It's not random. `a.*?b` outperforms on very short strings, `a[^b]*b` is faster on longer strings. "short" being something like 5 or 10 characters, but I don't quite care enough to find the breaking point. I've concluded that the "greedy" solution should be preferred as it's faster in all cases where `n` is big enough to matter and the difference is negligible where it isn't.