# Matching until the first instance of a positive look-ahead assertion

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm making a Ruby parser for [Fountain](http://fountain.io), a markdown-like plain text syntax for screenplays. Here's a pattern that isn't doing what I hoped it would do. My pattern is: stuff followed by `*markdown-style-emphasis*`. I'd like to use it to extract the stuff before the first instance of emphasis

```
pattern = /(.+)(?=(?:\*.+\*))/
```

- The following outputs `nil` because there's no match; the positive look-ahead assertion is dissatisfied. That's fine.

  ```
  pattern.match("hello")
  ```
- The following outputs `hello`. It gave me everything up until the emphasis. That's what I want.

  ```
  pattern.match("hello *world*")[1]
  ```
- The following outputs `hello *world*`.The positive look-ahead assertion is satisfied because there is stuff followed by some markdown-style-emphasis, but the stuff includes markdown style emphasis. I was hoping it would be satisfied by the first instance, but it's not. Does anyone know a way to resolve this?

  ```
  pattern.match("hello *world* *lol*")[1]
  ```

I tried to do combined positive look-ahead and negative look-behind to express anything followed by an emphasis that isn't preceded by an emphasis, but I don't think that approach is possible because look-behinds can only assert on fixed-length patterns. There must be a way to do this, right?

I pushed a sort-of-working version [here](https://github.com/maxjacobson/smashcut/commit/c3ea96786f61bc9d536fed5eb296d74077ae9791#diff-ce615373641345934f21ee0a6a201b8fR396), with one test marked as pending with `xit`.

**EDIT** (the test [now](https://github.com/maxjacobson/smashcut/commit/6388d8c2473ce94504de5aaf7c392eb322a4fadf) passes thanks to all of your help, thanks :))

Comment: Rather than framing the question in terms of what your pattern isn't doing, I suggest you first state what you want to do without reference to the pattern. Also, it's best to give a complete example with input and desired output. Here your input is a string, so you might write `str = "Quick brown fox *markdown-style-emphasis*"` and then say (for example), you want a pattern `p` such that `str[p] => "Quick brown fox "` (if that's what you want). Assigning the input to a variable (e.g., `str`) allows readers to reference the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: There's no rush to select an answer. Many people here wait at least a couple of hours before doing so. A quick selection may discourage other, sometime better, answers, and imo is discourteous to those still working on their answers. In case you don't know, you can vote on answers to your questions and can change the selected answer as many times as you like. (I'm not advocating the latter here--just wanted you to know.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the feedback! I've been reading SO for a long time but this is my first question, so I'm not super familiar with the etiquette. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might make your regexp not greedy:

```
#             ⇓
pattern = /(.+?)(?=(?:\*.+\*))/

puts pattern.match("hello *world* *lol*")[1]
#⇒ "hello "
```

For this particular case, I would use ruby [predefined global $`](http://rocket-science.ru/tips/2013/02/26/ruby-predefined-globals/#backtick):

```
pattern = /\*.+\*/ # match whatever is to be actually matched
#⇒ /\*.+\*/
▶ pattern.match("hello *world* *lol*")
#⇒ nil
▶ puts $`  #` c’mon, parser
#⇒ "hello "
```

This is more semantic, in my opinion.

Comment: Depending on how this is to be used by the OP, neither the capture group nor the non-capture group may be needed:  `"hello *world* *lol*"[/.+?(?=\*.+\*)/] #=> "hello "`.

Comment: ah, that's neat. I generally avoid using the global variables because, tbh, they confuse me. I suppose `$PREMATCH` (via [english.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/English.rb#L44)) would make it pretty clear, though

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks. I'm eventually going to be passing the regex as an argument to `StringScanner#match?`. You're right that I won't need the capture group, I just included it for the sake of the example :)

Answer (score 3):

@mudasobwa's second answer is the most straightforward.

Regarding the first answer though, it is one way to go, but another (more efficient way) is to use `[^*]`. Besides that, you have redundant parentheses (captures) that will slow down the match.

```
pattern = /[^*]+(?=\*.+\*)/
pattern.match("hello")
# => nil
pattern.match("hello *world*")[0]
# => "hello "
pattern.match("hello *world* *lol*")[0]
# => "hello "
```

Comment: ah that's neat too. the `[^...]` notation means "anything but these characters" right? but `*` means "everything".... so I'm interpreting `[^*]` as "anything but everything" which is kind of a beautiful phrase but I don't really understand how this works

Comment: `*` and certain other characters do not have special meaning when in a character class (`[  ]`) `[^*]` means any character other than an asterisk.

Comment: @sawa Any proof on this is more efficient than matching `*text*` and getting prematch? I doubt it is faster and my tests show nearly same performance.

Comment: ahhh makes sense. Thanks for the clarification @CarySwoveland. In my real-world usage, I need to match multiple kinds of emphasis (imagine `*italics*`, `**bold**`, `_underline_`, `_**underline and bold**_`) so this approach might not scale up to that

Comment: @mudasobwa Non-greedy match generally requires backtracking, which will take time. As far as short strings are considered, the difference does the other way, though. [This](http://jsperf.com/test-non-greedy-vs-greedy-performance) may be useful, which cites a SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686233/difference-between-non-greedy-search-and-negated-character-set/24686564#24686564).

Comment: @sawa I understand why it is better than non-greedy, I do not understand why it is better than the second option I suggested ($`).

Comment: @mudasobwa Your second answer is great. I missed that part. Sorry. I edited my answer to mention that.

Comment: `[^*]` is not exactly correct.OP wants to a pattern of  `*something*` which is not same as what you are suggesting.For ex. `hello**yo *asds*` will work with the accepted answer but not yours.

Comment: @vks You are correct that they match different things. I assumed that that is an invalid pattern.